# Install and enable exif

Tags: linux, centos, apache-2.4, centos7

I moved my website to a `vps` and I used `exif` function but look like in this new server `exif` not installed or enabled.. I tied many ways to enable it but no success:

**Information:**

> Linux, Apache, Centos7

First, I run `php -m` but there is no `exif` in list.

**options.conf**

```
php1_release=7.2
php1_mode=mod_php
```

**configure.php72**

```
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-exif
```

**php.ini**

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

But still I got:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   exif_read_data() in...

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you get PHP from?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHP 8 here.

Edit your php.ini which is probably in /etc/php

Page down to "Dynamic Extensions"

Uncomment this line...

`extension=exif`

Save.

Exif is included, so there's nothing to install.

Restart php-fpm for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If php.ini contents is like this:

```
1   extension=php_mbstring.dll
2   extension=php_exif.dll
```

make sure in your PHP installation `ext` directory `php_exif.dll` is present.

If it's not there, get it from [here](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).